# Git connection timeout and attempt

Tags: ssh, git

in a script I need to call `git archive`, that in turn calls `ssh`:

```
git archive master --remote=user@gitserver.url.org:path/repo.git file
 \_ /usr/bin/ssh user@gitserver.url.org git-upload-archive 'path/repo.git'
```

I would need ssh to be called with the parameters `-o ConnectTimeout=1 -o ConnectionAttempts=1`, but only once (I can't change the configuration of git or ssh)

How can I modify the `git archive` command line to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The environment variable `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` allows you to override the default SSH application (`ssh`) with an alternate command and arguments.

For example, in your case, you'll want to use:

```bsh
export GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -o ConnectTimeout=1 -o ConnectionAttempts=1"
git archive master --remote=user@gitserver.url.org:path/repo.git file
```

There is also a `GIT_SSH` environment variable that allows you to specify just an alternate command (no arguments), so if you need to do this multiple times, then you could use a script:

```bsh
echo '#!/bin/bash -eu' > ./my_ssh
echo 'ssh -o ConnectTimeout=1 -o ConnectionAttempts=1 "${@}"' >> ./my_ssh
chmod +x ./my_ssh

export GIT_SSH="./my_ssh"
git archive master --remote=user@gitserver.url.org:path/repo.git file
```